# How to fix error with has_and_belongs_to_many creation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I want to create a record in join table but rails shows me two errors in two situation, and I don't want to generate a third model.

```
@channel = Channel.find(params[:channel_id])
 if @channel.users.create!(channel_id: params[:channel_id], user_id: params[:user_id])
     flash[:success] = "U Succeed:)"
     redirect_to request.referrer
 else
     flash[:danger] = "U Nit Succeed:H"
     redirect_to request.referrer
 end
```

second situation

```
 if Channel.users.create!(channel_id: params[:channel_id], user_id: params[:user_id])
     flash[:success] = "U Succeed:)"
     redirect_to request.referrer
 else
     flash[:danger] = "U'r Not Succeed:H"
     redirect_to request.referrer
 end
```

I want to save `attrs` in join table. According to rails official site guide, what's wrong?

First error:

> unknown attribute 'channel_id' for User.

Second error:

> undefined method `users' for Class:0x00007feaa0312058

Comment: Can you post your model's code for each? Also for the second scenario, it's an `undefined method 'users' for Class0x00007..` bc the association is on an instance of Channel, not the class itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you have associations like these:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :channels
end

class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

Now you are trying to do like this:

```
@channel.users.create!(channel_id: params[:channel_id], user_id: params[:user_id])
```

This will try to create a new `User` class object as there is no Model in between you just have a mid table. Instead you can do it like this:

```
# If you don't have the user object already
user = User.find params[:user_id]

# This will create a record in the mid table
@channel.users << user
```

This will create a new record in the mid table and the existing records will also exist as it is. And if you do like this:

```
@channel.users = user
```

This will delete all the existing associated user records from the mid table for this channel and add a new associated record with this user.

And when you try doing like this:

```
Channel.users.create!(channel_id: params[:channel_id], user_id: params[:user_id])
```

This is not valid at all because the class `Channel` doesn't have any direct relation with the `User` but an instance of `Channel` class may be associated with instances of `User` class.

Comment: yes it's the same code.   it's work and no error. but user and channel id save instead of each other

Answer (score 0):

For the first scenario i would suggest you should do it like

```
@channel.user_ids = @channel.user_ids  + [params[:user_id]]
```

it will create join table records, you can surely try optimised approach for this as you see fit.

Comment: thanks. this work like above solution, no error but the same problem i mentioned has exist yet

Answer (score 0):

you can use push or << method instead of create : Channel.users.push(attrs) or Channel.users << (attrs)  and second answer in good too but .ids not very readable 
or you can find channel by id and use it : channel.users.create(attrs)

see [api.rubyonrails.org](https://api.rubyonrails.org) and search has_and_belongs_to_many methods in searchbar